# Duplicating each dataframe value n times

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a data in csv that looks like this: [original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYtER.png)

I am trying to rewrite the csv and make my data to look like this:
[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkDcJ.png)

I can't seem to get individual data of the time column.

```py
dataset = pd.read_csv('/data.csv', index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
timeCol = df['Time']
print(timeCol)
counter = 0
for index, row in timeCol.itertuples():
    if(counter < 2):
        print(row)
        counter +=1
    else:
        counter =0
```

1. I will have an error at `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'itertuples'`. Why is that so?
2. My logic seems wrong, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `df.melt('Time',var_name = 'Shape',value_name = 'Color')`

Comment: Thanks @ansev do you want to post an answer for that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ansev

```
newdata = df.melt('Time',var_name = 'Shape',value_name = 'Color')
```